# awk concatenate lines of files and files into single file

Tags: awk, concatenation

I would like to concatenate several lines of a file to a single line and then again each file separated as a new record in the file.

file1.txt

```
aaa bbb ccc
ddd eee fff
```

file2.txt

```
hhh iii jjj
kkk lll mmm
```

newfile.txt

```
file1.txt aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff
file2.txt hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm
```

This is what I came up with, but can't get the files separated as records.

```
 gawk  -v ORS=" " "LF != FILENAME { print FILENAME; LF=FILENAME }; {$1=$1} 1; END { printf("\n");}"  *.txt >newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite @Jose Ricardo Bustos M. solution as

```
for f in file{1,2}.txt; do printf "%s %s\n" $f "$(tr '\n' ' ' <$f)"; done
```

or for an awk solution

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{f=FILENAME;a[f]=f} 
             {a[f]=a[f] FS $0} 
          END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file{1,2}.txt
```

can be simplified if your awk supports ENDFILE.

Comment: Thanks, script works. GAWK supports BEGINFILE/ENDFILE. But how shall it be simplified?

Comment: you can get rid of the array and the loop; concatenate fields on a variable and print and reset var at ENDFILE.  Something like this `awk 'BEGINFILE{a=FILENAME} {a=a FS $0} ENDFILE{print a}' file{1,2}`

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use `tr`,

```
for f in `ls file*.txt | sort`; do 
    printf "%s %s\n" "$f" "$(cat $f | tr '\n' ' ')"; 
done
```

you get

```
file1.txt aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff 
file2.txt hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm
```

**Awk solution**

```
awk '
LF != FILENAME{
    LF=FILENAME; 
    if(NR>1) printf "%s\n", s
    printf "%s ", LF; 
    s="";
}
{s=s $0}
END{printf "%s\n", s}' file*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one-liner,

```
for f in *.txt; do printf "%s " $f; sed 'N; s/\n/ /g' $f; done >  newfile
```